# Simple StackEx API request fails in swift

Tags: xml, swift, nsstring, stackexchange-api

I'm trying to pull down some XML from api.StackExchange. I've tried several things in Xcode playgrounds, but this is my latest attempt, in it's entirety:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var error: NSError?

var apiXML = NSString(
    contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "api.stackexchange.com/answers?site=stackoverflow"), 
    encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, 
    error: &error)
```

That last line is getting the error: **Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_1386_BPT, subcode=0x0)**

Frankly, I have no idea what this error means and I would really appreciate somebody helping me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a valid URL:

`"api.stackexchange.com/answers?site=stackoverflow"`

If you change it to:

`"http://api.stackexchange.com/answers?site=stackoverflow"`

The code you posted works perfectly.